# prove the positivity of n by n matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, computational-mathematics

I am trying to show that [det $(\frac{1}{\eta_{j}-\lambda_{i}})_{ij}$] is positive, such that
$\lambda_{1}, \ldots , \lambda_{n}$ and $\eta_{1}, \ldots , \eta_{n}$ are real numbers which satisfy the inequalities
$$ \lambda_{1} < \eta_{1} \leq \lambda_{2} < \eta_{2} \leq \ldots \leq \lambda_{n} < \eta_{n} .$$

Comment: you probably need a slightly stronger condition. If $\lambda_i=\eta_i$, you have a division by zero.

Comment: oh yes, thank you much i change the condition, it can not be $\lambda_{i} = \eta_{i}$

Comment: This is a [Cauchy determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix), which admits a closed-form formula.